# how can i ignor letter in arry and print number

Tags: php

i have this array

$mix = [1, 2, "A", "B", "C", 3, 4];

i want to know

Numbers Printed and Letters Ignored

and add  the first index with the last index

//output

```
"4 Numbers Printed"
"3 Letters Ignored"
```

"1+ 4 = 5"
"2+ 3 = 6"

Answer (score 1):

Here you go buddy:

```
$mix = [1, 2, "A", "B", "C", 3, 4];

$mixLength = count($mix);

$i = 0;
$num=0;
$char = 0;

while ($i < $mixLength) {
    if(is_numeric($mix[$i])){
        echo $mix[$i];
        $num++;
    }
    else {
        $char++;
    }
    $i++;
}

echo "<br>";
echo $num . " Numbers Printed";
echo "<br>";
echo $char . " Letters Ignored";
```